# Add two figures without deleting the first one

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I am trying to create Pong game and I need to add two figures. I used add() method but it only shows the second figure and clear the first one. My code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo extends JFrame{

    Paddle playerPaddle = new Paddle(26);
    Paddle aiPaddle = new Paddle(576);

    public Demo() {
        super("Ping Pong");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(624, 351);
        add(aiPaddle);
        add(playerPaddle);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo gui = new Demo();
        gui.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So, it only shows `playerPaddle`. How can I write it to show both `aiPaddle` and `playerPaddle`? Thanks in advance))).

Comment: Custom paint both paddles. They should **not** be components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JFrame` by default, uses `BorderLayout`. When you `jframe.add(component)` with a border layout, it is equals to `jframe.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER)`. So you are adding 2 components to `CENTER` border layout constraints. However, [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) can have only one component in its center. That's why you see this "override".

Change the layout, and you will see both components. Or change the constraints of at least one component:

```
  add(aiPaddle,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  add(playerPaddle);
```

I suggest you to take a look at [a visual guide to layout managers.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)